# The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup in XML.xml

Tags: xml

The error that I am getting in the xml file.

> The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

Below is a simplified structure of the XML.xml file that I have:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<company>
  <fw>
   <prod version = "1.1" >
   </prod>
   <comp_Addons>
     <hello1/>
     <hello2/>
   </comp_Addons>
  </fw>
</company>
```

The problem occurred in `<hello1>` right after `<comp_Addons>`. What should I do to make it well-formed?

Comment: Neither `<hello1>` nor `<hello2>` have been closed.  For example, `<hello1></hello1>` or alternately `<hello1/>`.

Comment: Also `<company>` and `<fw>` are never closed.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to include the / for <company><fw><hello1><hello2>. I actually had that closed.

Comment: Since posting your question you have corrected your XML to make it well-formed. Does this mean the problem has gone away?